# Use ENV variables in god config file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, god

I want to use environement varible in my god config file. I am using

```
queue       = ENV['ENCODE_QUEUE'] || "encoding_abc"
```

and setting ENCODE_QUEUE using

`export ENCODE_QUEUE="enocding_xyz"` in ~/.bashrc file. but the god service always uses 'encoding_abc"
How do i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible your god service is not loading the `~/.bashrc` file?

If `god` is running from a non-interactive shell, you will need to put the export in `~/.bash_profile` instead. Also make sure it is running as your user.